# Nginx redirect to domain.com > /blog while still able to specify domain.com/mycustomdir

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm using Nginx 1.0.15

I want to redirect domain.com > domain.com/wordpress BUT I still want to have the abililty to browse specifically to domain.com/mycustomdirectory Such as domain.com/files/

Here is my current config. There are rewrites in here already.

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  domain.com;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
}
        location /twitter {
        rewrite ^ http://twitter.com/name permanent;
}
        location /music {
        rewrite ^ http://domain.com:8080 permanent;
}
        location /plus {
        rewrite ^ http://gplus.to/name permanent;
}

     error_page  404              /404.html;
     location = /404.html {
       root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

Comment: I figured it out. I just added a second location with this.

    location = / {
    rewrite ^ domain.com/wordpress permanent;
    }